# JDBC - can't connect remotely to MySQL Server

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I can't connect (using JDBC) to a MySQL database hosted on my home computer(windows 8.1), from a laptop(Windows 7) connected to another network. As a connection url i use "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.102:3306/.." and I've granted all privileges to the user i'm trying to connect with. I have commented #skip-networking and #bind-address (I also tried with bind-address=0.0.0.0).

The thing is, if I bring the laptop to my home (on the same network as the computer hosting the database), it works just fine, but it doesn't connect anymore when the laptop it's connected to external networks.

Thank you!!

Comment: you need to have public IP then only you can work remotely on different networks

Comment: _"connected to another network"_ How are the two networks connected? If you have to go across the external Internet to get from one to another then this is going to require setting up some port forwarding at the server's Internet router.  Probably a question for [networkengineering.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Problems.

## *1

U Try to connect to the Database using the localNetworkIP.
open https://www.whatismyip.com/ on the Host, then u get the Internet IP of the Computer.
CAREFULL, most likely ur Internet IP Changes over time ( every 24hours) or u have a static IP. if not u have to use a DynDNS Provider to connect ur changing ip addresses to a DNS Domain.

## *2

The PORT 3306 has to be open in the router of the HOST.

Answer (score 2):

IP addresses 192.168.XXX.XXX are local addresses, which means they can't be reached from beyond the boundary of the router, Unless you set up port-forwarding on the router.

When you connect from outside the network on a particular port on your WAN address the connection will be forwarded to the pc/port you set up in the router.

There are some very good online tools that help you with the configuration like http://portforward.com/.

*Be advised that forwarding / opening ports on your router might make your network more vulnerable to hacking.*